# Are there any difference between irr (Incidence Rate Ratio) and exp (beta) coefficient?

Tags: regression, poisson-regression, incidence-rate-ratio

I am wondering that are there any difference between IRR (Incidence Rate Ratio) and the exp(beta) coefficient?

Comment: beta is a parameter over here.

Comment: Isn't the exponential of beta interpreted as the incidence rate ratio? i.e. if you add X by one, the incidence rate (Y) will multiply by exp(beta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Poisson model, the IRR associated with a one-unit change in $x$ is

$$\frac{E[Y \vert z, x+1 ]}{E[Y \vert z, x ]}=\frac{\exp \{\alpha + \beta_1 (x+1) + \beta_2 z\}}{\exp \{\alpha + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 z \}}=\exp \{\beta_1 \}$$

It's a multiplicative "effect" on the expected value.

You could also calculate a more general IRR for an arbitrary $\Delta x$ which is equal to $\exp \{\beta_1 \cdot \Delta x \}$.

I suppose it is also possible to define an IRR that compares two arbitrary expected values, like

$$\frac{E[Y \vert z, x+1 ]}{E[Y \vert z+1, x ]}=\frac{\exp \{\alpha + \beta_1 (x+1) + \beta_2 z\}}{\exp \{\alpha + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 (z+1) \}}=\frac{\exp \{\beta_1 \}}{\exp \{\beta_2 \}}=\exp \{\ \beta_1 - \beta_2\}$$

This would allow you to compare the change associated with $x$ and $z$. I am sure there are other comparisons that would make sense to do.

All this is to say that they are not technically the same and the latter is a special case of the former. They do often turn out to be the same in practice since the first seems the most common (at least in my little corner of the statistics world).