Interpreting coefficients in Log-linear model vs. Poisson regression model
I am trying to understand the difference in interpreting coefficients between log-linear regression and Poisson regression models. To clarify, when I use the term "log-linear regression", I am referring to linear regression where you take the natural logarithm of the outcome variable as a preliminary step (see this post which discusses the distinction).
From my understanding, both regression methods model the relationship $ln(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1{x}$. However, the interpretation of $\beta_1$ varies significantly by model.
To articulate this, I cite two online textbooks which introduce log-linear regression and Poisson regression, respectively:
Textbook on log-linear regression: If you scroll down to Key Concept 8.2, it states that within a log-linear regression $\beta_1*100$ can be interpreted the percent change in $y$ that result from a one unit change in $x$. In the textbook’s example, a regression of test scores on income (measured in \$1000 increments) returns a $\beta_1$ of $0.00284$. This can be interpreted as a one unit increase in income causes test scores to increase by $0.284\%$.
Textbook on Poisson regression: Interpreting $\beta_1$ in a Poisson regression requires exponentiating $\beta_1$. The resulting calculation expresses the relative size of $y$ after a one unit increase in $x$. The textbook gives an example of a regression of household size (i.e. number of people living within the household) on the age of the household’s head. The estimated coefficient $\beta_1 = −0.0047$ is exponentiated which returns the value $e^{-0.0047} = 0.995$. This is interpreted as a one-year increase in the age of the household head causes household size to decrease by $0.5\%$.
What is the reason for the difference in interpreting $\beta_1$ between log-linear regression models and Poisson regression models? Why do Poisson regression models require you to exponentiate $\beta_1$?

You can calculate the effect in levels using derivatives or finite differences. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/499087/7071 for formulas.

Exponentiated coefficients are explained here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/481541/7071
